# I keeping the error "error on parsing on input ins"

Tags: haskell

```
module HW2sol 
where import HW2types

ins :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
ins x [] = [(x,1)]
ins x (y:ys) =
    if x == fst y
        then (x, snd y + 1) : ys
        else y : (ins x ys)
```

HMW2types in this code is just a file that contains all of the declarations for the bag type.  I have even copied and pasted other functions from online and they get the same error. This function takes an element and adds it to a bag.

[2 of 2] Compiling HW2sol           ( HMW2sol.hs, HMW2sol.o )

HMW2sol.hs:5:1: parse error on input `ins'

Comment: It's easiest to answer questions about error messages when you include the full error message.

Comment: added the full error message

Comment: Cannot reproduce, compiles fine for me (assuming `type Bag a = [(a, Int)]`)

Comment: @bereal are you using ghci and then :load fileName? It just doesn't load for me

Comment: Hmm. I'd be checking on whitespace or weird characters in the file - especially at the start of the file. Or just re-create it from scratch.

Comment: I'm guessing everybody is reporting this working because they've taken out the `import HW2types`, since you haven't given us the source of this module. The problem doesn't actually depend on what's **in** the module, but it does depend on the OP's code being precisely as shown, with the import on the same line as the `where`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be aware of Haskell's indentation rules. Anywhere you have a block of declarations (as in a `let <decls> in <expr>`, or a `where`, etc) or a block of statements (as in a `do` block), or a block of patterns & branches (as in a `case` expression) Haskell identifies the start of each entry in the block by the following logic:

1. Identify the column of the first character of the first entry in the block. Call this column **C**.
2. The next line that is indented *less* than **C** indicates the end of the block (and is not part of the block).
3. Before the end of the block, any line that is indented *exactly* **C** characters starts a new entry in the block.
4. Before the end of the block, any line that is indented *more* than **C** is a continuation line of the previous entry

This logic is consistently applied to all of Haskell's "block" constructs. They all have to be aligned this way<sup>1</sup>. And it turns out that **the top-level declarations in a module form an aligned block**! We just don't usually bother to think of them that way because they are conventionally started at column 1 (which means it isn't possible to end the block as no line can start before the first column; people normally just put all their top-level declarations at the start of the line and indent any continuations without ever thinking about "aligning the module's main block").

However, your code does not (successfully) use this conventional layout. Because you didn't insert a linebreak after the `where`, the first declaration begins at column 7, not column 1!

```
where import HW2types
      ^
1234567
```

Your type declaration of `ins` begins on column 1, so by rule 2 above (1 is less than 7) this indicates the end of the module's block of definitions; the compiler has to parse `ins :: Eq a => ...` as something that can *follow* the main block in the module, instead of parsing it as a declaration *in* the main block. That's why you get a parse error (nothing can follow the main block).

If you start your module's main block at column 7 then **all** of your declarations have to be indented to column 7. This actually works:

```
module HW2sol 
where import HW2types

      ins :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
      ins x [] = [(x,1)]
      ins x (y:ys) =
          if x == fst y
              then (x, snd y + 1) : ys
              else y : (ins x ys)
```

However you'll probably find it much easier to simply put a line break after the `where` and have `import HW2types` on a new line.

---

<sup>1</sup> Alternatively, blocks and their entries can be explicitly delimited with braces and semicolons. But this is not usual style in Haskell.